# Get value from v-select

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, vue-select, laravel-9

I have a dropdown component that utilized vue-select that's populating states as a dropdown. When I choose an option from the dropdown the data is not getting grabbed. Here's my dropdown component.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label>States</label>
        <v-select label="name" :options="states"></v-select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            states: [
                {
                    "name": "Alabama",
                    "code": "AL"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Alaska",
                    "code": "AK"
                },
                {
                    "name": "American Samoa",
                    "code": "AS"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Arizona",
                    "code": "AZ"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Arkansas",
                    "code": "AR"
                },
                {
                    "name": "California",
                    "code": "CA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Colorado",
                    "code": "CO"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Connecticut",
                    "code": "CT"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Delaware",
                    "code": "DE"
                },
                {
                    "name": "District Of Columbia",
                    "code": "DC"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
                    "code": "FM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Florida",
                    "code": "FL"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Georgia",
                    "code": "GA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Guam",
                    "code": "GU"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hawaii",
                    "code": "HI"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Idaho",
                    "code": "ID"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Illinois",
                    "code": "IL"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Indiana",
                    "code": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Iowa",
                    "code": "IA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Kansas",
                    "code": "KS"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Kentucky",
                    "code": "KY"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Louisiana",
                    "code": "LA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Maine",
                    "code": "ME"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Marshall Islands",
                    "code": "MH"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Maryland",
                    "code": "MD"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Massachusetts",
                    "code": "MA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Michigan",
                    "code": "MI"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Minnesota",
                    "code": "MN"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mississippi",
                    "code": "MS"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Missouri",
                    "code": "MO"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Montana",
                    "code": "MT"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Nebraska",
                    "code": "NE"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Nevada",
                    "code": "NV"
                },
                {
                    "name": "New Hampshire",
                    "code": "NH"
                },
                {
                    "name": "New Jersey",
                    "code": "NJ"
                },
                {
                    "name": "New Mexico",
                    "code": "NM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "New York",
                    "code": "NY"
                },
                {
                    "name": "North Carolina",
                    "code": "NC"
                },
                {
                    "name": "North Dakota",
                    "code": "ND"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Northern Mariana Islands",
                    "code": "MP"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Ohio",
                    "code": "OH"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Oklahoma",
                    "code": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Oregon",
                    "code": "OR"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Palau",
                    "code": "PW"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Pennsylvania",
                    "code": "PA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Puerto Rico",
                    "code": "PR"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Rhode Island",
                    "code": "RI"
                },
                {
                    "name": "South Carolina",
                    "code": "SC"
                },
                {
                    "name": "South Dakota",
                    "code": "SD"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tennessee",
                    "code": "TN"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Texas",
                    "code": "TX"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Utah",
                    "code": "UT"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Vermont",
                    "code": "VT"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Virgin Islands",
                    "code": "VI"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Virginia",
                    "code": "VA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Washington",
                    "code": "WA"
                },
                {
                    "name": "West Virginia",
                    "code": "WV"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Wisconsin",
                    "code": "WI"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Wyoming",
                    "code": "WY"
                }
            ],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm using the component in my form component here.

```
<template>
    <div class="container col-lg-4 mx-auto bg-secondary p-5 mt-5" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .3;">
        <h3>Consumer Details</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="row mb-3 mt-4 p-2" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .3;">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <label for="consumer_name" class="form-label">Consumer Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consumer_name" id="consumer_name" v-model="consumer.name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <label for="consumer_address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="consumer_address"  v-model="consumer.address">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-1 d-inline-flex">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label for="consumer_city" class="form-label">City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="consumer_city" v-model="consumer.city">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" style="margin-top: 9px;">
                    **<StatesDropdown
                        v-model="consumer.state"
                        :options="consumer"
                        :filterable="true"
                    />**
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label for="consumer_zip" class="form-label">Zip</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="consumer_zip" v-model="consumer.zip">
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="height: 2px; width: 90%;" class="mt-5 mb-5 text-black mx-auto">
            <h3>Creditor Details</h3>
            <hr>
            <div class="row mb-3 mt-4" style="--bs-bg-opacity: .3;">
                <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                    <label for="creditor_name" class="form-label">Creditor Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="creditor_name" v-model="creditor.name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                    <label for="creditor_address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="creditor_address" v-model="creditor.address">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-1 d-inline-flex">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label for="creditor_city" class="form-label">City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="creditor_city" v-model="creditor.city">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-top: 9px;">
                        <StatesDropdown  v-model="creditor.state" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label for="creditor_zip" class="form-label">Zip</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="creditor_zip" v-model="creditor.zip">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="onSubmit">Submit</button></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" v-show="show_download_link">Download Debt Letter</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {Link} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import StatesDropdown from "@/Pages/Partials/StatesDropdown";
export default {
    components: { StatesDropdown, Link },
    data() {
        return {
            consumer: {
                name: null,
                address: null,
                city: null,
                state: null,
                zip: null
            },
            creditor: {
                name: null,
                address: null,
                city: null,
                state: null,
                zip: null
            },
            data: [],
            show_download_link: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            const self = this.$data;
debugger;
            const params = {
                data: {
                    consumer: self.consumer,
                    creditor: self.creditor
                }
            }

            axios.get('/api/new_debt_letter',  { params }  ).then(response => {

                return response.data
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I select a state I'm not getting that value. Could someone tell what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `v-model` on `v-select` and your custom component `StatesDropdown` does not implement `v-model` [contract for custom components](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model)

It should look like this:

```js
<!-- StatesDropdown.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  data() {
    // .....
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() { return this.modelValue },
      set(newValue) { this.$emit('update:modelValue', newValue) }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <label>States</label>
    <v-select label="name" :options="states" v-model="model">
    </v-select>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Levy in the docs for vue-select it gives an example of using v-modal in v-select. https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting

Comment: What you said was correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to update several thing and `emit` change event for `v-select`.

Here is the update

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label>States</label>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-select
        label="name"
        :items="states"
        item-text="name"
        item-value="code"
        @change="$emit('input', $event)"
      ></v-select>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-vue-vuetify-forked-cnht47?file=/src/components/StatesDropdown.vue)

Comment: btw this seems like code for Vue2 while the question is tagged with Vue 3

Comment: Yes I'm still learning vue3. I stuck in vue2 mode because that's all I work with at work. But the app that I'm working on for testing is vue 3.